# Can't delete Red5 .ser files after recording

Tags: flash, red5

I'm recording audio/video for individual slides using Red5 and FB 4.6 on Windows. Occasionally it will not complete the recording and leaves .ser and .info files.  We can't re-record because the .ser files can't be deleted.  Running process explorer, it shows that Red5 has those files locked.

I've tried the workaround identified in https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/wiki/Repairing-Recordings but that doesn't unlock the files nor get rid of the .ser and .info.  Restarting Red5 releases the files but stopping Red5 when others are trying to use it too is not feasible.

So, how do I (1) Stop creating those .ser and .info files and (2) Delete or remove them without stopping Red5?

Comment: Sorry... should have said I'm using 1.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Windows locks the files and I'm not certain there's much we can do about it. Linux doesn't have this issue.

Comment: I installed the 1.0.6 snapshot version of Red5 and for some reason the problem has gone away.   However, we're also making sure that we don't try to play the file before the .ser file goes away.  In any case, it's working great now.